# WPF (XAML): Shortcut key Event

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, key, shortcut

I have a problem with my XAML. I have a Menu Component, and I would like that it would work in Shortcut key too. I have XAML code, which doesn't work:

```
  <MenuItem Header="_New" Name="New" Click="New_Click" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N">
 <MenuItem.InputBindings>
 <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="control"/>
 </MenuItem.InputBindings>
 </MenuItem>
```

What is the solution? New_Click event works, but Shortcut key doesn't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `InputGestureText` is only going to add text to the menu item per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You need to specify what needs to happen when the shortcut is actually performed.  To do that you need to create an ICommand in your ViewModel, preferably, then bind that command to the `MenuItem.Command`

So your resulting code should look like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="_New" Name="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N">
```

assuming you have a `public ICommand NewCommand {...}` in your view model.

**EDIT**

Doing this requires a command because that's how WPF works.  WPF != WinForms, where in WinForms you would use events and in WPF you want to try to use `ICommand` bindings.  This is proven, and answers your question on why Command is required: it is because [InputBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements the Command design pattern, so you're not going to really get a way to work around it.

So there isn't really a way to work around using the `Click` event handler instead of a `Command` with input gestures.  If you're not in the position to use a Command as they are intended to be use (like in MVVM), then you will have to add an ICommand in code-behind, then programmatically set up the binding.

```
private RelayCommand qatRemoveItemCommand;

public ICommand RemoveItemCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this.RemoveItemCommand == null)
        {
            this.RemoveItemCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.RemoveItem(), param => CanRemoveItem);
        }
        return this.RemoveItemCommand;
    }
}

private void RemoveItem()
{
    this.DeleteItem();
}

private bool CanRemoveItem
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}

KeyBinding RemoveItemCmdKeyBinding = new KeyBinding(
    this.RemoveItemCommand, 
    Key.N, 
    ModifierKeys.Control);

New.InputBindings.Add(OpenCmdKeyBinding);

<MenuItem Header="_New" Name="New" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N">
```

Note it may be required that you Remove or clear the InputBindings when the control is unloaded, but I think this will be as close as you can get, not to mention my original answer answer's your question; your request for additional information is a separate question in itself.

Also, do some research on the classes that implement inherit from InputBinding, [KeyBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [MouseBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to apply shortcut on click.We need to use command binding to achieve this functionality through XAML.
   First of all,you need to bind command to the MenuItem and then bind the same command to keybinding.
 Following is the working code for that:

```
 <MenuItem Header="_New" Name="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N">

        <MenuItem.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="control" Command="{Binding NewCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </MenuItem.InputBindings>
    </MenuItem>
```

**NewCommand** will be of  Icommand type in your ViewModel.
I am providing C# code for your understanding of command binding:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyData();
    }


}
public class MyData 

{
    public MyData()
    {
        this.NewCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteShowMessage);
    }

    private void ExecuteShowMessage(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
    public ICommand NewCommand { get; set; }

}
```

Above code will  work as per your requirement.Please Let me know if you have any queries regarding this.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Here's my utility class for that:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace NNN
{
    /// <summary>This utility class translates ICommand calls to RoutedEventHandler calls</summary>
    class c2e : ICommand
    {
        readonly RoutedEventHandler eh;

        public c2e( RoutedEventHandler eh )
        {
            this.eh = eh;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        bool ICommand.CanExecute( object parameter )
        {
            return true;
        }

        void ICommand.Execute( object parameter )
        {
            var a = new RoutedEventArgs();
            this.eh( this, a );
        }
    }

    static class Hotkey
    {
        /// <summary>Register event handler for hotkey</summary>
        public static void registerHotkey( this Window wnd, Key key, ModifierKeys modifier, RoutedEventHandler handler )
        {
            ICommand cmd = new c2e( handler );
            InputBinding ib = new InputBinding( cmd,new KeyGesture( key, modifier ) );
            wnd.InputBindings.Add( ib );
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.registerHotkey( Key.O, ModifierKeys.Control, menuOpen );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As non of the above solutions worked for me, I would like to suggest another solution here, by using [`RoutedCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-routedcommand?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

**XAML**

```xml
<Window x:Class="CH02.ContextMenuDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CH02.ContextMenuDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.MenuItemClickCommand}" 
                    CanExecute="CanExecute"
                    Executed="OnMenuItemClicked"/>
  </Window.CommandBindings>

  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Right Click here to open Context Menu!"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap">

      <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>         

          <MenuItem Header="My Menu Item"
                    Name="MyMenuItem"
                    Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.MenuItemClickCommand}">
          </MenuItem>

          <Separator />
          
          <MenuItem Header="Another Menu Item"
                    IsCheckable="True"
                    IsChecked="True"/>
        </ContextMenu>
      </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CS**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static ICommand _clickCommand;

    public static ICommand
            MenuItemClickCommand => _clickCommand ??
                                    (_clickCommand = new RoutedUICommand(
                                        text: "Options",
                                        name: "MenuItemClickCommand",
                                        ownerType: typeof(MainWindow),
                                        inputGestures: new InputGestureCollection(
                                            inputGestures: new InputGesture[] {
                                                new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control)
                                        })));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Focus();
    }

    private void OnMenuItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Context menu item clicked!");
    }

    private void CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true; // or other logic
    }
}
```